# What is wrong with this setInterval() code of javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

Hi I am working on an application in Django. I have multiple threads running and I need to check the status of the threads periodically. So I used `setInterval()` but I want to stop it when I have exception in thread. But it is not stopping and keeps on calling the URL. Here is my code:

```
function checkThreadsStatus(){
   var g_progress_intv = setInterval(function() {
       $.post("some_url", function(json_response) {
           var jsonObj = eval("(" + (json_response) + ")");
           if (jsonObj.exceptionOccur){
               clearInterval(g_progress_intv);
               g_progress_intv = 0;
           }
           else{
               //do some stuff
           }
           });
    }, 2000);
 }
```

`jsonObj.exceptionOccur` is a `boolean` variable. But when it is `True` `setInterval()` does not `Stop`.

Comment: It should be `true` not `True`. What is the JSON response? Why are you parsing it with `eval`?

Comment: Just FYI, you can do `$.post('url', function(json){}, 'json')`.  This makes jQuery auto-parse your JSON, so you don't need the `eval`.

Comment: You should not have to so the `eval()` if you set the correct content type on the server to `application/json`. Plus jQuery has http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: @pimvdb if i passed `exceptionOccur = True` from my `django view` it will be treated as a `true` in `javascript`.

Comment: Do you ever get into the if condition?

Comment: OK i will remove the `eval`. Can any one tell me the solution for original problem?? i shall be very thankful to you.

Comment: @Leo yes i did get into it when it is true. I double checked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling the `checkThreadsStatus()` function multiple times? The intervals might possibly be stopping, but you are declaring them on top of each other. Use some alerts or `console.log` in there to determine the actual state of the variables.

Comment: I also thought that i might have calling the `checkThreadsStatus()` two times but it is not. It is a single call for it.

Answer (score 0):

What if you define your `var g_progress_intv` before your `setInterval`? But it should be working as you got it, there's nothing wrong with your definition.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/fH6c9/2/

```
function checkThreadsStatus(){
    var g_progress_intv;
    g_progress_intv = setInterval(function() {
```

Instead of your eval you should use `$.parseJSON()`

If you call `checkThreadsStatus()` within an interval, the timeout will only be resetted once of the X number of intervals set.

**What is the response of your server?**

Comment: Isn't this exactly equivalent to what the OP has?

Comment: i already declared the variable `g_progress_intv` as global variable. e.g. `var g_progress_intv = 0;` before calling the `setInterval()`

Comment: putting the var in front of it only makes it accessible to the checkThreadsStatus() function, not global